# How can I aggregate data based on sub query results

Tags: sql-server

I have a sql query like this:

```
SELECT (SUM(DURATIONSECS) / 3600.00) AS LaborHrs, 
(SELECT LABORLEV2 t2 FROM LABOR WHERE LABORID = t1.LABORID) As Dept
FROM Table1 t1 
WHERE DTM BETWEEN 'datetime1' AND 'datetime2' AND 
(SELECT LABORLEV1 FROM LABOR WHERE LABORID = t1.LABORID) = '100' 
AND PAYCODEID='1'
Group BY LABORID
```

This gives me the correct data like this:

```
LaborHrs        Dept
90.5000000      office
1033.2500000    retail
522.2500000     retail
217.5000000     misc
1145.5000000    misc
40.0000000      retail
```

However I need the results to be aggregated if the dept name is the same for instance I need the sum of all labor hours of "retail" and "misc" to be in the same column. I have tried grouping by Dept, but it did not recognize that column name.

Comment: GROUP BY only works when the column you picked is already available through the FROM clause, hence you will need to join it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rewrote your query based on what I understand of your question, but I'm pretty suspicious of this part:

```
DTM BETWEEN 'datetime1' AND 'datetime2'
```

I assume that it is a datetime variable or number that you would substitute in.
If that is the case, I guess here might be the answer.

```
SELECT (SUM(DURATIONSECS) / 3600.00) AS LaborHrs, 
    , l1.LABORLEV2 AS Dept
FROM Table1 t1 
    JOIN LABOR l1 ON l1 ON l1.LABORID=t1.LABORID
WHERE DTM BETWEEN 'datetime1' AND 'datetime2' AND l1.LABORLEV1='100'
    AND t1.PAYCODEID='1'
Group BY t1.LABORID, l1.LABORLEV2
```

Comment: Sorry I should have specified I just changed datetime values to datetime1 and datetime2.

Comment: Thanks, the only thing I needed to change was l1.LABORLEV2 to PAYCODEID in the Group BY Clause

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Group some column, the column can't be a subselect, so you will have to rewrite the query using JOINS.

By what I understant of your query, you can join the tables Tabl1 and LABOR and move your conditions to a single WHERE statement, something like this:

```
SELECT 
    l.LABORLEV2 AS Dept,
    (SUM(t1.DURATIONSECS) / 3600.00) AS LaborHrs
FROM Table1 t
INNER JOIN LABOR l ON t.LABORID=l.LABORID
WHERE 
    l.LABORLEV1='100' AND
    t1.PAYCODEID='1' AND
    t1.DTM BETWEEN 'datetime1' AND 'datetime2'
GROUP BY l.LABORLEV2
```